# jQuery doesn't work using an id or class selector

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I went through a tutorial to make a nested gridview in ASP.Net here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx. 
In the tutorial jQuery is used to show and hide the nested gridview. In the jQuery, he uses a src attribute that = something like plus or minus as the selector as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
        $(this).attr("src", "./Content/Images/minus2.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "./Content/Images/plus2.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove().fadeOut();
    });
```

I want to be able to instead use a class or id as the selector instead such as:

```
$("#collapserows").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
        $(this).attr("src", "./Content/Images/minus2.png");
    });
    $("#collapserows").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "./Content/Images/plus2.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
```

However, this won't work for whatever reason. The element I'm trying to select is an image:

```
<img alt="" id="collapserows" style="cursor: pointer" src="Content/Images/plus2.png" />
```

I thought that the attribute selector was selecting the img element. Shouldn't referencing the id also select the img element and work? I also tried a class and had no luck. The reason I want to be able to do this is so I can use the same image to collapse/expand the individual nested gridviews and collapse/expand all of the nested gridviews.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Additional code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="NestedGridView.aspx.cs" Inherits="NestedGridView" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/CSS/GridViewStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#collapserows").live("click", function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
            $(this).attr("src", "./Content/Images/minus2.png");
        });
        $("#collapserows").live("click", function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "./Content/Images/plus2.png");
            $(this).closest("tr").next().remove().fadeOut();
        });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView" 
            runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="AltRow" 
            RowStyle-CssClass="Row" 
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" 
            OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound"
            DataKeyNames="CustomerID">
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <img alt="" id="collapseallrows" style="cursor: pointer" src="Content/Images/plus2.png" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img alt="" id="collapserows" style="cursor: pointer" src="Content/Images/plus2.png" />
                        <asp:Panel style="display:none" runat="server">
                            <asp:GridView ID="InnerGridView" 
                                runat="server"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                Width="100%">
                                <Columns>

                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" Visible="false"/>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="CustomerIDLabel" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="EmployeeIdLabel" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Freight" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FreightLabel" Text='<%# Bind("Freight") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ship Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ShipNameLabel" Text='<%# Bind("ShipName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ship Address" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ShipAddressLabel" Text='<%# Bind("ShipAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ship City" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ShipCityLabel" Text='<%# Bind("ShipCity") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Postal Code" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ShipPostalCodeLabel" Text='<%# Bind("ShipPostalCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ship Country" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ShipCountryLabel" Text='<%# Bind("ShipCountry") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView> 
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="CompanyNameLabel" Text='<%# Bind("CompanyName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ContactNameLabel" Text='<%# Bind("ContactName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Title" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ContactTitleLabel" Text='<%# Bind("ContactTitle") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="AddressLabel" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>    

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="CityLabel" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Postal Code" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="PostalCodeLabel" Text='<%# Bind("PostalCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="countryLabel" Text='<%# Bind("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="PhoneLabel" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete example. Since your working with the DOM, an example of it (your HTML) is needed.

Comment: `*=` is a contains selector. `[src*=plus]` matches a src attribute that contains "plus" in it.

Comment: are you doing this in a dom ready state?

Comment: I don't think it's in a dom ready state. I provided all of the markup. Also, I assumed *= is a contains selector, I just want to know why I can't use an id or a class

Comment: I thought that since I was using an html element (<img>) inside of an asp control it would still work though. When I view the source inside the browser, it shows all img tags with an id of collapserows. Is the source I'm viewing within the browser still different from what's actually being rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

For further information read:
**[$( document ).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**

Try this :

### HTML

```
<img alt="" id="plus" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
```

### JavaScript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#plus").live("click", function () {
        if ($(this).attr("src")=="images/minus.png")
        {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png")
            $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
            $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this. I'll go read through what you linked.